# Можно ли оставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и, авторская-пунктуация

**Он посмотрел на Винсента, который устроился на диване рядом, и тоже катал вино по бокалу, тоже думал о чём-то невесёлом.**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, запятую перед **и** можно объяснить авторской пунктуацией или это таки ошибка и надо ее ликвидировать?

Comment: На мой взгляд, лишняя

Comment: а вот на мой взгляд - она там нужна для усиления паузы. Хотелось бы узнать обоснованное мнение экспертов. Спасибо.

Comment: при наличии авторской запятой, по моему мнению, трудно понять кто "тоже катал вино по бокалу, тоже думал о чём-то невесёлом." Винсент или тот, кто на него посмотрел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Он посмотрел на Винсента, который **устроился** на диване рядом **и** тоже **катал** вино по бокалу, тоже **думал** о чём-то невесёлом.*

В придаточном предложении, присоединенном к главному местоимением [который](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/90842) (союзное слово), имеются однородные сказуемые: **устроился и катал, думал.**
При таком их расположении запятая перед союзом **и** не нужна.

[Запятая перед союзом «И»](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)

2. Хотите, чтобы была пауза? Тогда напишите так:
   *Он посмотрел на Винсента, который **устроился** на диване рядом, **и** тоже **катал** вино по бокалу, **и** тоже **думал** о чём-то невесёлом.*

Или так (с интонационным тире):
*Он посмотрел на Винсента, который устроился на диване рядом, — тоже катал вино по бокалу, тоже думал о чём-то невесёлом.*